# sum of cells if they are less than 1000 if more than 1000 then input difference

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I am really not sure how to word this.
I am trying to come up with a formula that the weekly total does not exceed 1000 anything over is non-qualified "sales amount"

**- Example:

Monday - Friday total = 1700 Monday 300 Tuesday 400
Wednesday 500 Thursday 300 Friday 200**

****The formula would need to be able to come up with something like this**

**Monday 300 Tuesday 400 Wednesday 300 Thursday 0 Friday 0**

**Non qualified**
**Monday 0 Tuesday 0 Wednesday 200 Thursday 300 Friday 200******

My formula looks like this

`=IF(SUM(C6:F6)<=$F$2,F6,SUM(D6:F6)-1000)`

The first couple of numbers was calculating correctly because the actual total is less than 1000 but once the weekly total is more than that is not calculating.

Not sure what am doing wrong and I've already watched so many video tutorials.. kind of stumped.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the values are in row 2, and the threshold value in F1, so put this formula in A3:

```
=IF(SUM($A$2:A2)<=$F$1;A2;IF(SUM($A$2:A2)-$F$1<A2;$F$1-SUM($A$2:A2)+A2;0))
```